# Unable to create windows 7 repair disc

Tags: windows-7

This is what I get when using the maintenance tool in the start menu on windows 7 to create a repair disc. I have yet to find a google search solution that works. I can ordinarily write to the cd/dvd drive. I've tried different discs, logging in with the hidden admin account, etc.

```
System repair disk could not be created.
The parameter is incorrect. (0x80070057)
```

This has always been a ridiculously buggy area for NT derived systems and I have always given up on their system restore/repair tools and just used Bootit NG. Have you been able to get the repair disc create to work?

Comment: Some solutions in this thread...http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/d21642ff-4e06-4e57-ac1e-beacdfb77168

Comment: @Moab: very good thread. Looks like I would need to create the recovery directory. I have the original setup disk, but will probably keep using Bootit as I still don't trust microsoft's backup/restore.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to repair your system with (you guessed it) a Windows 7 repair disc.

Fortunately, the Windows 7 install DVD [behaves as a repair disc](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Start-your-computer-from-a-Windows-7-installation-disc-or-USB-flash-drive) as well. No need for one if you have that (any edition works).

Just hit the `Repair Your Computer` link under the Install button in the bottom left corner.

Answer (score 1):

I had to shut down encryption software (BoxCryptor Classic and TrueCrypt) to make this error go away.

Answer (score 1):

If you use TrueCrypt, the answer might be simple: unmount all encrypted drives and try again. Windows is unable to play nicely with encrypted mounts. Originally from [this Microsoft forum answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/system-repair-disc-could-not-be-created-the/278cb626-45a6-491e-abbd-74b0c6ac73c8).

Answer (score -1):

I have also found that if BitLocker is turned on you can't create a Windows 7 repair disc.  Turn off BitLocker and it should work fine.